# geopandas sjoin returning empty rows

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a table of polygons of all UK output areas structured as such:

```
newpoly


        OBJECTID    OA11CD  LAD11CD Shape__Are  Shape__Len  TCITY15NM   geometry
67519   67520   E00069658   E06000018   3.396296e+04    1006.464423 Nottingham  POLYGON ((456069.067 340766.874, 456057.000 34...
67520   67521   E00069659   E06000018   1.014138e+05    1404.327776 Nottingham  POLYGON ((456691.549 340778.104, 456557.864 34...
67521   67522   E00069660   E06000018   1.812783e+04    731.882609  Nottingham  POLYGON ((456945.994 340821.233, 456969.220 34...
67522   67523   E00069661   E06000018   2.765546e+04    1112.317587 Nottingham  POLYGON ((456527.178 340669.119, 456484.993 34...
67523   67524   E00069662   E06000018   3.647822e+04    964.989153  Nottingham  POLYGON ((456301.845 340419.759, 456244.357 34...
```

and a table of points structured like:

```
restaurants

    name    latitude    longitude   geometry
0   Restaurant Sat Bains with rooms 52.925050   -1.167712   POINT (-1.16771 52.92505)
1   Revolution Hockley  52.954090   -1.144025   POINT (-1.14403 52.95409)
2   Revolution Cornerhouse  52.955517   -1.150088   POINT (-1.15009 52.95552)
```

but when i do:

```
spatial_join = gpd.sjoin(restaurants, newpoly, op = 'contains')
spatial_join
```

0 rows match.

the geometry column of the restaurants were made via:

```
restaurants = pd.read_csv('Restaurants_clean.csv')
restaurants = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    restaurants, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(restaurants.longitude, restaurants.latitude))
```

I have tried different 'op' arguments but the same problem occurs. I am convinced that there must be a join because all UK output areas exist in the table.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different projections. I am sure GeoPandas `sjoin` actually warns you about that. Create your point layer in the following way:

```py
restaurants = pd.read_csv('Restaurants_clean.csv')
restaurants = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    restaurants, 
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(restaurants.longitude, restaurants.latitude),
    crs=4326)
restaurants = restaurants.to_crs(newpoly.crs)
```

I am first specifying the CRS of input (as 4326, which is EPSG code of WS84, i.e. lon/lat coordinates) and then I am re-projecting the data to the same CRS `newpoly` has (I assume 27700).

Comment: Yes this solved, the issue. I didn't receive a warning but this may be because i'm using vscode

Comment: Yes, for some reason VSCode suppresses warnings by default.